# Pandas fails to remove some rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am struggling for a while with a very weird situation that makes me feel confused.
So I cannot remove those few rows from my dataframe and I don't know what is the problem with that.

[image: this is an issue]

Comment: please include an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Should be `test2 = test2.drop([455, 756, 790, 1444])` I believe. You're only removing the Values from that _column_ but not from the DataFrame.